# Is there a magic item that grants the same benefit as the 6th-level Totem Barbarian's eagle totem?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, vision-and-light

I want to make a sniper character but there are only two things that make this possible: the Totem Warrior barbarian's 6th-level eagle totem and the Sharpshooter feat.

The [Path of the Totem Warrior barbarian](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/barbarian#PathoftheTotemWarrior) gets this benefit from the Eagle totem for its 6th-level Aspect of the Beast feature (PHB, p. 50):

> You gain the eyesight of an eagle. You can see up to 1 mile away with no difficulty, able to discern even fine details as though looking at something no more than 100 feet away from you. Additionally, dim light doesn’t impose disadvantage on your Wisdom (Perception) checks.

This means you can see clearly from 600 feet away - the maximum distance you can shoot with a longbow. And the first benefit of the [Sharpshooter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/sharpshooter) feat (PHB, p. 170) negates that disadvantage on long-distance shots.

**Is there a magic item that provides the PC the same benefit as the Totem Warrior barbarian's 6th-level eagle totem?**

I can see the need to multiclass barbarian/rogue, but if I could just build from the rogue class with a single magical item that offers some damage benefits.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Another note that might cause problems for your idea of a rogue-only sniper build: rogues aren't proficient with longbows anyway (they're martial ranged weapons).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89347/discussion-on-question-by-hyde-is-there-a-magic-item-that-grants-the-same-benefi).

Answer (score 23):

> ### [Eyes of the Eagle](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/eyes-of-the-eagle)
>
> These crystal lenses fit over the eyes. While wearing them, you have advantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight. In conditions of clear visibility, you can make out details of even extremely distant creatures and objects as small as 2 feet across.

While it doesn't specify an exact distance, these would be your best bet.

Of additional note, as V2Blast points out, a rogue/barbarian multiclass would have longbow proficiency, but a solo rogue does not. You can address this by getting proficiency through a race ([elves](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/elf#ElfTraits)), feat ([Weapon Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/weapon-master)), or item ([Bracers of Archery](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bracers-of-archery)).

Comment: I'll allow myself to be a little pedantic here, but this item is not **the same** as the barbarian totem bonus: It is much better.

Comment: Yes and no. This item has a lot less specifics than the totem bonus, which means it's up to the DM to decide what "extremely distant" means, and how fine the detail is. It also has the clear visibility condition, while the totem says "see with no difficulty".